# How to find files of certain extension and tar each of them in to another location

Tags: linux, bash, scripting, command-line-interface, tar

I have script for finding files of certain type and compress them to a single tar archive and put in to other place. But now, there is a change in requirement, that I need to find files of certain type, list it and compress each of them to a tar archive and put it to other place. Currently I'm using the script

```
cd /to/top/of/dir/structure
tar -cf /path/to/tarfile.tar --files-from /dev/null # trick to create empty tar file
find . -type f ! -name '*.log' -print0 | xargs -0 tar -uvf /path/to/tarfile.tar
```

which I have taken from this post : https://superuser.com/questions/436441/copy-every-file-with-a-certain-extension-recursive

So, the above script find certain file type and then archive it as single tar file and then place it to another location. But my question is, I need to find files of certain type, list them, tar each of the listed files and put them into other location.

Comment: What do you mean by list it?

Comment: Like, finding the files of certain types and list them using stdout in console or store it in a file.

Comment: so you want to make a list of the files that you have put in the tar file ?

Comment: No, after finding the files of certain type, I would like to list it and then tar each of the listed files to a certain location.

Comment: ...but you are already doing that, no?  Are you saying you want to handle multiple types of file?  If so, add more `find` statements to your script -- they will be run sequentially

Comment: Ok, files are listed. But the thing is, the above script will only make a single tar archive of all the listed files. But I need to make tar archive of each listed files. Hope you got my point :)

Comment: A tar of each file (file1.tar, file2.tar,...,filen.tar)? Or a tar of each group of files (*.log, *.tmp,...,*.etc)?

Comment: A tar of each file. (File.tar, tile2.tar, ...,filen.tar).

Comment: Any particular reason?  You know `tar` doesn't strictly *compress*, right (unless you add `-z` for a gzip file)?  You might be better off with straight gzip for a per-file approach

Comment: A tar of each file doesn't make any sense. If you want to compress the files, use `gzip` instead of `tar`.

Comment: Ok. As per your recommendation, gzip is good. But how do I implement or modify the script to do so? I'm new to scripting.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm going with...

```
cd /to/top/of/dir/structure
find . -type f ! -iname '*.log' -exec gzip -c {} \> /path/to/gzips/\`basename {}\`.gz \;
```

...but I haven't tested it.

And I'm really dubious it will be what you really need...

---

### Edit

I can get it as far as...

```
find /path/to/top-level -iname "*.log" -printf "gzip -c %p > /path/to/gzips/%f.gz\n"
```

...to output the commands you would want to run.

I'm still working on executing those commands, short of `-fprint`ing to a temp file, `chmod +x` and executing *that*.

Not to mention dealing with any issues escaping awkward characters in filenames.

---

### Edit #2

OK, I can't get it down to one line (which was my challenge, not yours), but I can get it into a fairly simple script:

```
#!/bin/bash

function compress_file {
  BASENAME=`/bin/basename "$1"`;
  /bin/gzip -c "$1" > /path/to/gzips/$BASENAME.gz;
}

export -f compress_file;
/bin/find /path/to/top-level -iname "*.log" -exec /bin/bash -c 'compress_file "$0"' {} \;
export -fn compress_file;
```

Comment: Thanks. But its not working. It produces some strange outputs in console in weird characters.

Comment: This should work `touch {file1,file2,file3,file4}.txt file10.log; find . ! -name '*.log' -type f -print0 | xargs -0 tar cvf tarr.tar {} \;  2>/dev/null`

Comment: That satisfies the Ops original goal. However after reading the dozens of comments on the OP it is clear that there is a new goal: bzipped copies of the log. (one file per log, not one big tar).

Comment: Edited answer...

Comment: Thanks.But it only lists the files, not compressing it.

Comment: ...which is what I said in the edit.  You would have to run the statements it returns to do the actual compression.

Comment: OK, edited again...

Answer (score 3):

Without a pipe (or xargs), creating several tar files instead of just one, and deleting the non-compressed files, here is how you can do it:

```
find /path/to/files -name "*.ext" -type f -exec tar -czf {}.tar.z {} \; -exec rm {} \;
```

Comment: Alas!  I don't think very many of us speak French very well.  I've tried to translate you, though.  Feel free to edit it if my French is bad.

Comment: I think  'tar.z' be 'tar.gz'  since the .gz extension is more common.

Answer (score 1):

Find the files and build a list, tell tar to make an archive from the list....

```
find /path/to/files -name "*.ext" | tar cJfTP /path/to/archive.txz -
```

Side note: your example doesn't compress the file, it just archives it.

Answer (score 0):

find . -type f ( -name "*.php*" -o -name "*.js" -o -name "*.css" -o -name "*.crt" -o -name "*.htm*" -o -name "*.txt" -o -name "*.$" -o -name "*.xml" -o -name ".ht*" )  -print0 | tar -czpf $FILE --null -T -